# Write a program that asks the user to enter a power . Then find the last digit of 2 raised to that power?

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that asks the user to enter a power . Then find the last digit of 2 raised to that power ?

Comment: Yes please solve it as I dont understand this question

Comment: I need it in python language . I am beggginer to python language

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. See https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F for more appropriate starting points.

Answer (score 0):

`power = int(input("Enter power: "))
ans = 2**power
print(ans % 10)`
If you want to repeat it so you can use a loop otherwise, this is the code.